# How to get proper line breaks for code cells when converting iPython notebook to tex?

Tags: python, latex, ipython, tex

I am writing a documentation for a python application. For this I am using iPython notebook where I use the code and the markdown cells. I use pandoc to transform the notebook to a .tex document which I can easily convert to .pdf.

My problem is this:
Line breaks (or word wrap) does not seem to work for the code cells in the .tex document. While the content of the markdown cells is formatted nicely, the code from the code cells (As well as the output from this code) is running over the margins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the same question. It looks like in python 2.7 you can add the following line to a file called custom.js:

IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineWrapping = true;

Custom.js is located in ~\Lib\site-packages\notebook\ or ~\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\

Note, however, that this isnt working for me yet. I will update here as soon as I get something working.

Comment: Update: As far as I know there is no solution to this.